# Android JSON URL fetching

Tags: android, json

Alright I'm trying to create a app for my Android Design team and I'm running into a snag that I can't seem to figure out.

Here's my json file the app is suppose to be reading from.

```
 {
  "status": "ok",
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "type": "post",
      "url": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=4712980303859595180",
      "status": "publish",
      "title": "Google Developer Page",
      "content": "<p>Here's a link to our Google Play Developer Page!</p>",
      "date": "December 24 2016",
      "attachments": [
        {
          "url": "http://technologx.com/android/ghostninja/header.png",
          "mime_type": "image/png"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's the logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
                  Process: com.technologx.firebirddesigns, PID: 32228
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
                      at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
                      at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
                      at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:156)
                      at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
                      at com.technologx.firebirddesigns.Fragments.StoreFragment.getJSONFromUrl(StoreFragment.java:169)
                      at com.technologx.firebirddesigns.Fragments.StoreFragment$DownloadFilesTask.doInBackground(StoreFragment.java:128)
                      at com.technologx.firebirddesigns.Fragments.StoreFragment$DownloadFilesTask.doInBackground(StoreFragment.java:112)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I've tried several different hosts with the json file like right now it's on jsonblob.com and it's not working with that site either. It keeps crashing either when I open the app or go to the store tab which is what is reading the json file.

Comment: clearly, you have made an error in describing the JSON format in your code. Or, you may be receiving a different JSON altogether than what you expect. Did you try using a tool to read the raw response? I suggest using Postman

Comment: This is what I have in the apps code     String url = "https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonblob/0fb02288-ca4e-11e6-b16a-3ba84d91f90e";
        new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url);  the source is here https://github.com/rgocal/GSD_Mobile

Comment: Code doesn't matter. check if the raw response is correct first. Use https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en

Comment: I can't figure out how to use that app and it won't allow my to import the json code

Comment: So @AnkurAggarwal how is that Chrome app suppose to help me with this?

Comment: Its not meant to import code. Its meant to make a network hit "manually" and then check if the response you receive is the same as that you expect. No shortcuts for good programming

Comment: It received it and had line 2 highlighted @AnkurAggarwal

Comment: @Technologx post your doInBackground()